# asp:GridView textbox always return blank value 

Tags: .net, asp.net, gridview

I added some textboxes to gridview using following code

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="STD<br/>ID">
       <ItemStyle BackColor="LightBlue" />
          <ItemTemplate>
          <div style="font-size:xx-small; overflow:hidden;">
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtStandard" EnableViewState="true" Height="10" Font-Size="XX-Small" Width="50" Text='<%# bind("STANDARD_ID") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
       <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtenderDemo" runat="server" 
            TargetControlID="txtStandard" ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList"
            MinimumPrefixLength="1" CompletionInterval="1000"
            EnableCaching="true" CompletionSetCount="20">
        </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
                        </div>



                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

I want to save updated values to database, But when I try to access values using

```
string strs = ((TextBox)TwoHeadedGridView1.Rows[0].FindControl("txtStandard")).Text;
```

It always returns me the blank value for all the rows,  Same thing happens for dropdown list it returns me originally selected value i.e. value selected at the time of writing dropdown box, there are no duplicate ids present on my asp form , This is my first interaction with customizing gridview,  I want to somehow make it run,

Can anybody suggest me any correction...

I did checked that any duplicate id is present in it or not,

Comment: At what point are you trying to obtain the updated value?

Comment: I have submit button which calls server side function which calls find control of gridviewrow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem here:
http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/29602882/gridview--cant-get-text.aspx

Remember that the web page is fundamentally a stateless thing!

When your `GridView` fires an event, your `Page_Load` method executes and *then* the method that handles the `GridView` event executes.  I still can't believe my eyes, but it seems that even if you manually assign the values from the `GridView` datasource to your TextBoxes, the value that the user typed in gets wiped out when the `GridView.DataBind` method executes.

**In short,** if your code is like mine, you have these two lines of code in your `Page_Load` method:

> myGridView.DataSource = someDataSet;
>     myGridView.DataBind();

**To solve this problem, change it to the following:**

> if (!IsPostBack)
>   {
>   myGridView.DataSource = someDataSet;
>     myGridView.DataBind();
>   }

By the way, I work in VB.net, so please do let me know that I converted to C# correctly for you.  I want to hear that this works for you too!

Answer (score 0):

Where are you trying to access those values?  If you are accessing them in the `RowUpdated` function, the values will be blank.  Access them during `RowUpdating`, and make sure to cancel the update.

Comment: I believe I am having an identical problem with a page I am working on and I am for sure accessing the values from the method that handles the `RowUpdating` event.